# Missing 2.2 GB of space on my micro SD card

Tags: sd-card, file-system, file-management

I pulled my micro SD card out of my phone (LG G3) and inserted it into my PC (Kubuntu 14.04). I was in the process of moving several large video files off of the SD card onto my computer. Moving these videos would have given me 4.0 GB of free space on my SD card.

As the process appeared to finish, I encountered an error that said the last of the files (2.5 GB) could not be deleted (from the SD card). And my file manager could not access the directory (/DCIM/Camera) that held the video files I was moving.

I safely ejected the SD card, then re-inserted it. Everything appears fine and the video files I was moving are all apparently gone. However, there is only 1.8 GB of free space on the SD card, not the 4.0 GB of space that there should be available.

How do I recover this missing free space? I would prefer to use my Linux desktop tools to do the job.

Comment: Well, that's something weird I would say why don't you try formatting your SD card using PC and see if you can get the space back ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there were problems with the file system (which your error message suggests), broken files may have been "re-allocated". For such things, *nix systems have a special directory on each file system, usually called `LOST+FOUND` or, on FAT file systems, `LOST.DIR`. Whenever things could not be "assigned to a file", they are placed there with some "cryptic" names.

So I'd suggest you mount the card on your Linux PC again, and check for that directory. If there's something in that directory, that could be the "broken" video files, and you simply could delete them to re-gain your space.

Comment: Thanks. I actually recovered even more space than I expected. I have 5.5 GB free now.

Comment: So it looks like this wasn't the first time something like that happend. Glad we were able to solve it!